# SQL Server | Agrupar linhas e dividir seus valores

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Gostaria de agrupar a linha 1 e 2 dos resultados da query e dividir seus valores (Valor1/Valor2). A tabela é a seguinte:

[image: Tabela de Resultados da Query]

Preciso que resulte no seguinte:

1 - % Conversão de orçamentos - 0,944

A Query que a gerou esses resultados é:

```
SELECT
    'Quant média diária vendas', AVG([VALORORIGINAL]) AS Valor1, 0 AS Valor2, [tipo]
    
    FROM [dbo].[VIEW_MU_INDICADORES_SF]

        WHERE TIPO = 'QUANTIDADE VENDAS'

GROUP BY TIPO

UNION

SELECT
    'Quant média diária orçamentos', AVG([VALORORIGINAL]) AS Valor, 0 As Valor2, [tipo]
    
    FROM [dbo].[VIEW_MU_INDICADORES_SF]

        WHERE TIPO = 'QUANTIDADE PEDIDO VENDAS'

GROUP BY TIPO

UNION

SELECT
    '% Conversão orçamentos', CASE WHEN TIPO = 'QUANTIDADE VENDAS' THEN SUM([VALORORIGINAL]) END AS Valor, CASE WHEN TIPO = 'QUANTIDADE PEDIDO VENDAS' THEN SUM([VALORORIGINAL]) END AS Valor2, [TIPO]
    
    FROM [dbo].[VIEW_MU_INDICADORES_SF]

        WHERE TIPO = 'QUANTIDADE VENDAS' OR TIPO = 'QUANTIDADE PEDIDO VENDAS'

GROUP BY TIPO
```

A View informada na Query é:

[image: View completa]

Já tentei algumas soluções postadas aqui para perguntas correlatas, mas nenhuma funcionou.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Se entendi : nomear a 1@ coluna , agrupar por ela , retirar o "tipo" do agrupamento.

Comment: Motta, a primeira coluna, não é uma coluna da view portanto não consigo agrupar por ela (ou não sei como fazer). 

Se eu tirar o tipo do agrupamento, retorna o erro:

 "...is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: para retirar evitar esse erro experimente colocar o Case dentro do Sum e especificar um valor fixo para a coluna Tipo no último trecho

Answer (score 0):

Experimente utilizar o código abaixo:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN [TIPO] = 'QUANTIDADE VENDAS' THEN AVG([VALORORIGINAL]) END
    /
    CASE WHEN [TIPO] = 'QUANTIDADE PEDIDO VENDAS' THEN AVG([VALORORIGINAL]) END      
    AS '% Conversão orçamentos'
    FROM [dbo].[VIEW_MU_INDICADORES_SF]
        WHERE TIPO = 'QUANTIDADE VENDAS' OR
        TIPO = 'QUANTIDADE PEDIDO VENDAS'
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: resolvido, obrigado.